# Get number of certain place of long number

Tags: flutter, dart, integer

How can I get a number of a certain place, for example, when I have a number like 12345, I need the number on the second place, so in this case the 2. A few more examples that you get the idea:

346775 => 4

673456 => 7

099784 => 9

How is this possible in Dart/Flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the number to a `String` and get the element at index `1` from the `String`.

```dart
void main() {
  final int longNumber = 12345;  
  final int numberAtSecondPlace = int.parse(longNumber.toString()[1]);
  
  print(numberAtSecondPlace); //2
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `split`. `String` do already have the `[]` operator which can be used to get a specific letter in the `String`.

Answer (score 2):

Not saying this is the most efficient way to do it. But it is the easiest way I can come up with right now.

```
void main() {
  print(346775.digitAt(1)); // 4
  print(673456.digitAt(1)); // 7
  print(099784.digitAt(1)); // 9
}

extension DigitAtOnInt on int {
  int digitAt(int index) => int.parse(toString()[index]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void main() {
  int num1 = 346775;
  String num1s = num1.toString();
  List num1l = num1s.split('');
  print(num1l[1]);
}
```

Comment: What does this answer improve when compared to the other answers? As I also told Victor, you don't need to call `split`. You can use the `[]` operator directly on a `String` to get a specific letter.

Comment: I just added it for a different answer. Thank you for the -1

Comment: Well, your answer is less efficient than the others and also less type safe (`num1l[1]` returns `dynamic` because of your `List num1l = num1s.split('');`). So I voted your answer down since the answer is actually not something that should be used.

Comment: as you wish mate